# GitHub Probot : ERROR probot : signature does not match event payload and secret

Tags: github, github-api, probot

I am trying to build a GitHub app using [Probot Framework](https://probot.github.io/).

Here's the content of file `index.js`:

```
module.exports = (robot) => {
  robot.log('Yay, the app was loaded!');
  robot.on('*', async context => {
    robot.log('Some event occured!');
  });
}
```

However, when I am run this app, after installing it in a repository, I received this error:

```
03:38:34.831Z ERROR probot: signature does not match event payload and secret
  Error: signature does not match event payload and secret
      at verifyAndReceive (/mnt/e/GSoC/test/test/node_modules/@octokit/webhooks/middleware/verify-and-receive.js:9:19)
      at IncomingMessage.request.on (/mnt/e/GSoC/test/test/node_modules/@octokit/webhooks/middleware/middleware.js:53:5)
      at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
      at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
      at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

What is the problem behind this error? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 9):

It says, `signature does not match event payload and secret`.

The possible reason behind this is that the `WEBHOOK_SECRET` in `.env` file of the repository doesn't match with `Webhook secret (optional)` in 
https://github.com/settings/apps/your-app-name.

Correctly configuring webhook secret will fix this error.

[image]