# GitHub probot : signature does not match event payload and secret

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, github-actions, probot

I am aware of this question [GitHub Probot : ERROR probot : signature does not match event payload and secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547841/github-probot-error-probot-signature-does-not-match-event-payload-and-secret). In my case the problem is a bit weirder. So when I'm running my application on the localhost and it is receiving github hooks via proxy https://smee.io/ everything works fine. But (with exactly the same env variables) when I'm hosting my application on kubernetes I got following error `GitHub probot : signature does not match event payload and secret` and I know that according to linked question it has something to do with Webhook secret but I do not understand why the same variable is working on localhost and give errors on k8 (ofc is in base64). My app is done according to documentation https://probot.github.io/docs/development/#use-server. I suspect that it might be connect with `x-hub-signature-256` but it shouldn't be a problem since when I check Webhook secret on k8 pod I can see that it is correct. Any ideas what can be cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while but the problem was in the base64 encoding of the secret. It contained new line character and because of it, the secret looked valid on the terminal. So to sum up this error was solely connected with secret correctness.